# Mono Cecil - Initializing a local variable

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I have the following method:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

I want to modify this code with Mono Cecil. I want to create an instance of a custom class within the method:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  MyClass instance = new MyClass();
  Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Currently I use the following code:

```
  var constructorInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
  MethodReference myClassConstructor = targetAssembly.MainModule.Import(constructorInfo);

  var processor = targetMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();
  var firstInstruction = targetMethod.Body.Instructions[1];

  var instructions = new List<Instruction>() {
      processor.Create(OpCodes.Newobj, myClassConstructor),
      processor.Create(OpCodes.Stloc_0)
  };

  foreach (var instruction in instructions)
  {
      processor.InsertBefore(firstInstruction, instruction);
  }
```

After applying those changes, the program is invalid and cannot be executed.
If i use 'IL DASM' to look at the generated code the following statement is missing:

```
.locals init ([0] class [MyAssembly]MyNamespace.MyClass instance)
```

The rest of the IL is the same, as if I directly compile the full code.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried it but by looking at the Cecil Source Code you should first create the local variable which is part of your `MethodBody`.

`MethodBody` has a `Variables` collection which can be filled via

```
body.Variables.Add( new VariableDefinition(typedef) )
```

Then you need to call `processor.Create(xxx,indexto local variable);`

That should do the trick. The only thing I did not see yet how you can get a `TypeDefinition` out from a `Type`. I think you need to load the assembly into Mono Cecil first before you can use this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to add the variable. Put I still have problems to initialize it with a call to the corresponding constructor.